# FileNotFoundError when using subprocess.call() to convert mp3 to wav using ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I am trying to convert an MP3 file to a WAV file using the ffmpeg command-line tool in Python. Here's the code I'm using:

```
import subprocess

# convert mp3 to wav file
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', 'C:\\Users\\Ashlar Global\\Desktop\\Project\\Firefly_Replica\\audioFiles\\JROppenheimer.mp3', 'converted_to_wav_file.wav'])
```

However, when I run this code, I encounter the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I've installed ffmpeg on my system, and I can run it from the command prompt, so I'm not sure why it's not working within the Python script. The path to the input MP3 file and the desired output WAV file are correct.

How can I resolve this FileNotFoundError and successfully convert the MP3 file to WAV using ffmpeg in my Python script?

Keep in mind this very code works on Google Colab but not on my local system.

Comment: Make sure that the path to your file is correct.

Comment: It is. I've triple checked it. I've also tried all the ways a python can read the file.

Comment: I believe the problem is that it cannot find the `ffmpeg` executable.  Is it installed, and is it in your `PATH` environment variable?

Comment: See the red warning section in https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor: **For maximum reliability, use a fully qualified path for the executable. To search for an unqualified name on `PATH`, use `shutil.which()`** -- but do test for whether `shutil.which()` returns `None`, which it will do if your executable's location isn't listed in the PATH at all.

Comment: @binaryescape re "the path to your file" -- it's not the path to the mp3 that matters for this error, it's the path to where ffmpeg.exe is installed. Python has no way to build an exception when a C program it started can't find a file; it's _the act of starting the C program_ that can fail in such a way that Python finds out exactly what went wrong to build an exception object for it (other than a generic "failed with exit status 1" type exception, if `subprocess.run` is passed `check=True`).

Comment: @abdz_128, ...so, `print(os.environ['PATH'])`, and check whether the directory that `ffmpeg.exe` is in is included in that printout; if it's not, there's your problem; if it _is_, include that in the question so you're ruling out the obvious cause.

Comment: @Charles Duffy Thanks for the clarification. I guess the file not found exception ffmpeg.exe would throw, would not look like the one provided.

Comment: @binaryescape, right; C programs don't have "exceptions" at all (exception handling was introduced in C++), and they certainly don't make them look like Python exceptions.

Comment: @Charles Duffy my bad I should have called it error. Yes that makes sense ;)